# Find the domain of $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ given $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) =\sin 2x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Find the domain of $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ given $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x) =\sin 2x$

$D_f=\{x|x \geq 0\}$ and $D_g=\{ x|- \infty < x < \infty\}$

$f \circ g $ is defined when $\sin(2x) \geq 0$ :
$$D_{f \circ g} =\{x| x \in [ 0 + \pi n , \frac{1}{2} \pi +\pi n]\}$$

$g \circ f $ is defined when $x \geq 0$:
$$ D_{g \circ f}=\{x|x \in [0, \infty)\}
$$

The problem I have is when I draw the function $g \circ f$ using $y=\sin (2 \sqrt{x})$: the domain shows $( -\infty , \infty)$. How is this possible?
[image: $y=\sin (2 \sqrt{x})$]

Comment: Everything is okay until you plot the function, $\sin(2\surd x)$, for negative real values of $x$, which should return imaginary values.  The error is likely in your graphic application, which is clearly unable to handle the exception.

Comment: I think this graph shows the real part of this function.

Comment: @WongAustin The real part should be 0 for all nonpositive real $x$

Comment: @Graham Kemp You are right...

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible, I think. The graph is not true. We can not get something for $x<0$.

Because $$D_{g\circ{f}}=\{x|x\in{D_f},f(x)\in D_g\}=\{x|x\in[0,+\infty),\sqrt{x}\in\mathbb R\}=[0,+\infty).$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is the picture I plotted using desmos.

The thing about programming is if one forgot to take care of boundary cases, strange things appear.

$$D_{g\circ f} = \{x| x \in [0, \infty) \}$$ is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you plotted $g \circ f (x) = \sin(2\sqrt{x})$?

However you should get $0$ in $(-\infty,0)$, which is of course wrong, since the function is not defined there.
I guess it is because the program plots the real part of the function. When you evaluate $g \circ f$, e.g., at $x = -1$, you get $\sin(2\sqrt{x}) = \sin (2i)$ which has real part equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your domains are correct for the functions restricted to the reals.  To see what happens more generally you need to study the functions defined on the complex plane (and having complex values).  I.e.complex analysis. It's a 4-d situation really.  You could do something like take cross-sections...  But the graphing computer you're using probably  isn't prepared for this complication and is giving you a nonsense answer for negative x...